# How can I add name of xlab and ylab for each variable in Quantile regression plot?

Tags: r, plot, quantreg

I wrote this code for find the quantile regression plot with X-axis labels and Y-axis labels. But it only gives the plot without axis labels. How can I find the plot with axis labels for each variable.[image: This is the quantile regression plot which gives no axis labels but gives main labels]

```
library(quantreg)

quantile <- c(0.10, 0.20, 0.45, 0.70, 0.90)

fitqr <- rq(logbmi ~ age + total_children_born + education + 
              wealth + Residence + Region + Husband_educ + cur_work, 
            data=dat, tau=quantile , method="fn")
plot(summary(fitqr), lwd=1, pch=20 , cex=1.5, xlab="quantile", 
     ylab="coefficient")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to enlarge the margins with the `mar` option, e.g. `mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1)`.

#### Example

```
plot(summary(rq(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + 
                  Species, tau=quantile, method="fn", data=iris)),
     xlab="tau", ylab="coefficient", mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1))
```

[image]